# Adjusting the idle setting on a 2005 Cavalier

Tags: engine, ac, chevrolet

The air conditioning unit on my 2005 Cavalier only engages when the engine is idling above a certain level (observationally, it appears to be between 1000 and 1200 rpm).

During the summer months, then, I would like to adjust the idle rpm of the engine so that the AC runs even when sitting still.

How would I do that?

Other car specs (if needed):

- 4 cylinder
- automatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect something is wrong with your AC system if the compressor is not running at idle, assuming you're idling at the correct RPM.  Maybe a bad RPM sensor on the compressor?

Changing your engine idle is going to require editing your [PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powertrain_control_module).  If you're not idling in the correct range, check your [IAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_air_control_actuator).

Comment: fwiw - I had an Escort station wagon years back that did the same thing .. and it was "by design"